# Add multiple if statements in a single php CI fucntion

Tags: php, codeigniter

Nerd question, apologies, Below function works when there is only single if statement but when i add multiple if statements, it won't work, as far i know about php currently i used elseif statement but also id didn't worked

```
function NewNoticeMSG($insert_id) {
    $notice = $this->CI->notification_model->get_notice($insert_id);
    $stu_setting = $this->CI->setting_model->getSkoolInfo();

    if ($notice['visible_student'] == 'Yes') {
        $students = $this->CI->student_model->get_all_students();

        foreach($students as $student) {
            $MSG = "Dear Student, NOTICE " . $notice['date'] . ": " . $notice['title'] . " . Thank You, " . $stu_setting['name'] . ".";
            $content = 'AUTH_KEY=' . rawurlencode($this->AUTH_KEY) .
            '&message=' . rawurlencode($MSG) .
            '&senderId=' . rawurlencode($this->senderId) .
            '&routeId=' . rawurlencode($this->routeId) .
            '&mobileNos=' . rawurlencode($student['mobileno']) . 
            '&smsContentType=' . rawurlencode($this->smsContentType);
            $smsglobal_response = $this->sendSMS($content); 
        }
    }

    if ($notice['visible_parent'] == 'Yes') {
        $students = $this->CI->student_model->get_all_students();

        foreach($students as $student) {
            $MSG = "Dear Parent, NOTICE " . $notice['date'] . ": " . 
            $notice['title'] . " . Thank You, " . $stu_setting['name'] . ".";
            $content = 'AUTH_KEY=' . rawurlencode($this->AUTH_KEY) .
            '&message=' . rawurlencode($MSG) .
            '&senderId=' . rawurlencode($this->senderId) .
            '&routeId=' . rawurlencode($this->routeId) .
            '&mobileNos=' . rawurlencode($student['guardian_phone']) . 
            '&smsContentType=' . rawurlencode($this->smsContentType);
            $smsglobal_response = $this->sendSMS($content); 
        }
    } 

    if ($notice['visible_teacher'] == 'Yes') {
        $teachers = $this->CI->teacher_model->get_all_teachers();

        foreach($teachers as $teacher) {
            $MSG = "Dear Teacher, NOTICE " . $notice['date'] . ": " . $notice['title'] . " . Thank You, " . $stu_setting['name'] . ".";
            $content = 'AUTH_KEY=' . rawurlencode($this->AUTH_KEY) .
            '&message=' . rawurlencode($MSG) .
            '&senderId=' . rawurlencode($this->senderId) .
            '&routeId=' . rawurlencode($this->routeId) .
            '&mobileNos=' . rawurlencode($teacher['phone']) . 
            '&smsContentType=' . rawurlencode($this->smsContentType);
            $smsglobal_response = $this->sendSMS($content); 
        }
    } 
}
```

how should i do that??

Comment: all the `if ($notice['visible_parent'] == 'Yes') {` are same ????

Comment: yes all are same and all are true

Comment: @AbdullaNilam - they are not the same. It is `visible_student`, `visible_parent` and `visible_teacher`.

Comment: how, don't know :(

Comment: @AbhishekMishra - your code looks ok. What do you mean by **it won't work**? The code above is not working? If no, what part of code is not executing properly?

Comment: can you post your `get_notice()` function from your `notification_model`

Comment: i am sending sms through this code if i am only adding first if visible_student == yes it would send SMS but when i am adding visisble_parent visible_teacher if statement it wouldn't send it to any 3 above mentioned group.

Comment: @AbhishekMishra - try tu put `var_dump($notice);` in your code. Probably `$notice['visible_parent']` and `$notice['visible_teacher']` have different values than `Yes`.

Comment: @KeithAsilom `public function get_notice($id = null) {
    $this->db->select('send_notification.*')->from('send_notification');
    $this->db->where('send_notification.id', $id);
    $this->db->order_by('send_notification.date');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array(); 
}`

Comment: @shaggy yes it is

Comment: the model seems fine. can you post the result of `print_r($notice);`

Comment: Code refactoring, please! 90% of the code is the same!

Comment: @KeithAsilom i have checked the var_dump and everything is fine, i am getting data for all variables. but if ($notice['visible_student'] == 'Yes') returns unidentified index

Comment: solved bro $notice was the problem, i was querying result_array instead of row_array in the model which was making variable undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try with the :

```
function NewNoticeMSG($insert_id) {

    $notice = $this->CI->notification_model->get_notice($insert_id);
    $stu_setting = $this->CI->setting_model->getSkoolInfo();

    if (isset($notice['visible_student']) && $notice['visible_student'] == 'Yes') {
        $students = $this->CI->student_model->get_all_students();
        foreach($students as $student) {
            $MSG = "Dear Student, NOTICE " . $notice['date'] . ": " . $notice['title'] . " . Thank You, " . $stu_setting['name'] . ".";
            $content = 'AUTH_KEY=' . rawurlencode($this->AUTH_KEY) .
                    '&message=' . rawurlencode($MSG) .
                    '&senderId=' . rawurlencode($this->senderId) .
                    '&routeId=' . rawurlencode($this->routeId) .
                    '&mobileNos=' . rawurlencode($student['mobileno']) . 
                    '&smsContentType=' . rawurlencode($this->smsContentType);
            $smsglobal_response = $this->sendSMS($content); 

        }
    }
    if (isset($notice['visible_parent']) && $notice['visible_parent'] == 'Yes') {
        $students = $this->CI->student_model->get_all_students();
        foreach($students as $student) {
            $MSG = "Dear Parent, NOTICE " . $notice['date'] . ": " . 
            $notice['title'] . " . Thank You, " . $stu_setting['name'] . ".";
            $content = 'AUTH_KEY=' . rawurlencode($this->AUTH_KEY) .
                    '&message=' . rawurlencode($MSG) .
                    '&senderId=' . rawurlencode($this->senderId) .
                    '&routeId=' . rawurlencode($this->routeId) .
                    '&mobileNos=' . rawurlencode($student['guardian_phone']) . 
                    '&smsContentType=' . rawurlencode($this->smsContentType);
            $smsglobal_response = $this->sendSMS($content); 

        }
    } 
    if (isset($notice['visible_teacher']) && $notice['visible_teacher'] == 'Yes') {
         $teachers = $this->CI->teacher_model->get_all_teachers();
        foreach($teachers as $teacher) {
            $MSG = "Dear Teacher, NOTICE " . $notice['date'] . ": " . $notice['title'] . " . Thank You, " . $stu_setting['name'] . ".";
            $content = 'AUTH_KEY=' . rawurlencode($this->AUTH_KEY) .
                    '&message=' . rawurlencode($MSG) .
                    '&senderId=' . rawurlencode($this->senderId) .
                    '&routeId=' . rawurlencode($this->routeId) .
                    '&mobileNos=' . rawurlencode($teacher['phone']) . 
                    '&smsContentType=' . rawurlencode($this->smsContentType);
            $smsglobal_response = $this->sendSMS($content); 

        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: i have checked the var_dump and everything is fine, i am getting data for all variables. but if ($notice['visible_student'] == 'Yes') returns unidentified index

Comment: if (isset($notice['visible_student']) && $notice['visible_student'] == 'Yes')
 var_dump fails with undefined variable[visible_student]  under this statement while works fine if queried out of this statement

Comment: Message: Undefined variable: $notice['visible_student'] 

Filename: libraries/Smsgateway.php

Line Number: 99

Comment: and if i m running the var_dump out of if statement it's working fine

Comment: solved bro $notice was the problem, i was querying result_array instead of row_array in the model which was making variable undefined

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you need to on error reporting then you should print array what you get then use isset and !empty in if statement,

For example:-

```
if (isset($notice['visible_student']) && 
!empty($notice['visible_student']) && $notice['visible_student'] == 
'Yes')
```

instead of this, "if ($notice['visible_student'] == 'Yes')"

Hope it will help you!

Comment: i have checked the var_dump and everything is fine, i am getting data for all variables. but if ($notice['visible_student'] == 'Yes') returns unidentified index

Comment: solved bro $notice was the problem, i was querying result_array instead of row_array in the model which was making variable undefined